# How to install Python and wxPython offline?

Tags: installation, python

I could not install my modem driver so I have to update and install applications offline. For this I want to use `keryx` but to install `keryx`, Python and wxPython have to be installed first. So how do I install Python and wxPython offiline on Ubuntu 13.04?

**Note :** I don't have internet connection in Ubuntu. So I'll have to download the required file from my Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, installing packages offline is well... drama. You can download the `.deb` files from http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring, but you have to be very careful. You should  also download and install ***all*** dependencies, which can be tens and even hundreds for some packages. Normally, `sudo apt-get install [package_name]` does this all for you automatically, but doing it manually is a hell of a job.

That said: Base Python is installed by default on Ubuntu. 
wxPython is downloadable [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python-wxgtk2.8), but be sure to first download and install ***all*** dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I already installed python now i am looking for a guid line to install wxPython .                             **Note:** I am using Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit